Distributed file DB with data replication
I would like to use storage with data replication, what I mean:

the solution needs to be liteweight (no heavy database), I like the idea of eclipsestore (https://eclipsestore.io/), I would like a solution that consumes max 500MB or ram.
I want the instances to replicate data to each other. If I create a row in instance 1, I want to row to be replicate in instance 2.
I do not want to upload data to any cloud (eg. S3, DynamoDB), I would like to have instance to instance communication only,
Build in encryption would be an advantage.


Are there any requirements stopping you from just using any distributed database, e.g. YugabyteDB
